# Excel Web Access Not Disabled?

Tags: 2007, document-library, excel

I uploaded a spreadsheet to one of my sharepoint 2007 sites. When I click on the link I get the error "Exxel Web Access An error has occurred. Please contact your system administrator if the problem persists." The Excel Calculation Services are not enabled on any of our servers as we dont use it, I also went in and verified that the Document Library which contains this data has the Browser-enabled Documents option was set to Open in client Application.

Also I logged in as the SharePoint Admin we have, and I could click on the file and it allowed me to save it just fine. But when I am viewing the site as a vistor with no authentication I am getting the error. I checked my permissions and they all seem to be inline. But it is still trying to use the excel service any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was about permissions. When a user is granted only the read (view only) permission in SharePoint this forces the user to use the Excel calculation services. The only way around this is to grant the user at least the contribute permission. In my case this wasnt possible as these were anonymous users. The only 'fix' I found was a workaround, instead of uploading a .xlsx file you upload a .xls file and all is well.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you've set the Document Library to "Open as Webpage" then you're trying to use Excel Calculation Services.

Either start "Excel Calculation Services" on one of the servers and add the document library as a trusted source

Or set the Document library to "Open in client application"

Comment: Haha long day, I completely wrote that out wrong. I meant open in Client Application was checked.

Comment: One thing I have noticed too is that as an Admin I can download the file just by clicking on it, but when I am just browsing the site without any authentication it forces me to use the excel calc services.